# Symfony Yaml based routing doesn't work as generated

Tags: php, symfony

I'm following the Symfony3 intro.

I ran `php bin/console generate:controller` and followed the prompts, choosing YAML for the routing because I don't like comments as code.

It generated the following:

```
number:
    path:     /lucky/number
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Lucky:number }
```

And placed it into `src/AppBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml`

This doesn't work. However, copying the contents to `app/config/routing.yml` does.

It seems like I'm missing some additional config that it doesn't mention in the guide because it expects you to just use the annotations for the routes. It also doesn't mention anything in the [docs here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html) under the "using other formats" section.

Is copying the generated route into the other file the right thing to do? 
Is there an alternative step that tells it where to find the other YAML based routes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In you `app/config/routing.yml` you can do:

```
app:
    resource: '@AppBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml'
```

And then everything you write inside of `AppBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml` will work